# GraphQL.Parser.SourceException: Property "AverageRatings" is not a field of type Models ''Cars"

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, graphql

I am new to GraphQL and creating back-end using `GraphQL.Net`Nuget package with Web API.

Below is the schema I am generating:

```
        var db = new CarContext();
        schema = GraphQL<BeerContext>.CreateDefaultSchema(() => new CarContext());
        var car= schema.AddType<Cars>();
        car.AddField(b => b.Id);
        car.AddField(b => b.Name);
        car.AddField(b => b.AverageRatings);

        schema.AddField("car", new { id = 0 }, (db, args) => db.Cars.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == args.id));

        schema.Complete();
```

And Below is the Query I am running:

```
        var query = @"{
                        car(id:9) {
                            id
                            name
                            AverageRatings                            
                      }}";
```

The query works perfectly fine if I remove `AverageRatings` from above query, but once I include that it will give me this error:

```
GraphQL.Parser.SourceException: '``AverageRatings'' is not a field of type ``Cars'''
```

Can somebody help me out? Thank You

Comment: Try averageRatings instead of AverageRatings in your query. Looks like it makes the field names start with lowercase since id and name are not throwing errors

Comment: @vbranden I tried that but same exception :(

Comment: Problem solved, @vbranden thank you sir :)